# Share Outlook task reminders

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, office365, tasks

Under Outlook 2013 I shared a task-list from one Office 365 hosted Exchange account to another, then created a task with a reminder.

The task appeared within the other user's Outlook, however the reminder wasn't attached to the task.

Is it possible to share the reminder attached to a shared task?

Comment: A reminder was set on the task in Outlook by user A. User B could see the task, but not its reminder.

Comment: So there's no way that the creator can share their reminder on task?

Comment: Thanks for your help, however it's not meeting my client's unique requirement with shared tasklists where all parties have the same reminders set. Looks like I'll have to look at an alternative product.

Comment: You might try stackoverflow. A custom script that run for incoming tasks is likely what you'll need. Although the reminder date/time is not known and will have to be a default for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reminder can be set, but it is only works for the owner. Once a task is delegated to you, the owner of the task can not pass the reminder on to you. You have to set your own reminder.

A potential workaround may be to auto accept all tasks and then make a rule to flag for follow up at a specific interval. Or use VBA as part of a script rule to when processing delegated tasks.